# Get properties from Members in Umbraco (In Usercontrol)

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, umbraco, ascx

I've made a Umbraco site, and ive got some members that i need to display information about in a usercontrol(ascx) page.
But the only thing i can find is the old umbraco api, with the `m.GetProperty();` method like:

```
foreach (Member m in Member.GetAll) {
    m.getProperty("danceStyles");
}
```

But visual studio says that `Member` is obsolete and i should use `Membership` instead, but i dont know how i can get generic properties from a member through that.
Only thing i can get is `Username`, `Email` and `Password`, and not properties i define in umbraco...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yah, `Member.GetAll` is obsolete but I suppose you could use `Member.GetAllAsList()` this method is to get members in List, This method works for me

```
foreach (var member in Member.GetAllAsList())
{
    // to get Property
    var property = member.getProperty("danceStyles");

    // to get Property Value
    var propertyValue = member.getProperty("danceStyles").Value;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! thought it was the whole `Member` class that was obsolete so didn't even think of using that!

Answer (score 0):

Default properties of a member, such as Login, Email and Password can easily be referenced through .Net properties, however as you've noticed, custom properties can only be accessed by string.

The `getProperty()` method returns an `umbraco.cms.businesslogic.property.Property` object, so if you want to get/set the actual values of custom properties you've made, simply access the `Value` [.net] property of the [umbraco] property like so:

```
m.getProperty("danceStyles").Value
```

Comment: I've not played around with the `Membership` library yet, so perhaps someone could provide a more "up-to-date" answer.